# How can I add my data in my database if my data is in a form of JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How can I add my data in my database if the data is look like this?

```
{"category_id":"1","topic_id":"1","scenario_id":"1","scoring":"0","nonscoring":"0"}{"category_id":"3","topic_id":"4","subtopic_id":"10","scoring":"0","nonscoring":"0"}
```

I don't know what to do, can anyone help me?

Here is the code that I have currently.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $set_components = $request->get('set_components');

        foreach($set_components as $key => $value ) {

          $components[] = [
              'set_id' =>  1,
              'category_id' => ,
              'topic_id' =>,
              'subtopic_id' =>  ,
              'scenario_id' => ,
              'scoring' =>,
              'non_scoring' =>  ,
              'created_by' => Auth::user()->id
          ];
        }

        Set_component::insert($components);

        return response()->json([
          'success'=>$set_components
        ]);

    }
```

I just don't know on how can I add this response on my for loop to insert it on my database.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: decode json string, then access its contents. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: hi sir i am having this error ```json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given```

Comment: Your json string would be the `$value` inside the `foreach`. That's where you need to decode. Also, I think you would need to declare `$component` as an array before calling `foreach`. I'll post as an answer if you couldnt get it to work.

Comment: can you show me on how to do this sir?

Comment: i already tried to decode it, but i am just getting the error of ```json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given``` i really don't know what to do. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to decode your json. Give this a try:

```
$components = [];
foreach($set_components as $key => $value ) {
   //$value holds your json string
   $decodedValue = json_decode($value);
   $components[] = [
    'set_id' =>  1,
    'category_id' => $decodedValue->category_id,
 ];
}
```

Comment: hi sir, ```Use of undefined constant JSON - assumed 'JSON' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)``` this is the error that i am having.

Comment: Can you update your question with your revised code please?

Comment: its my bad sir, its already okay sir, thanks for the help sir, it really helped me a lot!